# How to change div padding percent using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a `responsive` window for playing videos.

```
.player-window {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 42%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I would like to change the `padding-bottom %` for each video that I click.
Heres is what I tried just guessing. It does not work but I think its clear what Im trying to do.

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
    $('.player-window').css(padding - bottom: '50%');
    $('.player-window').html('embedded video');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use or

```
$('.player-window').css('padding-bottom','50%');
```

or

```
$('.player-window').css({'padding-bottom':'50%'});
```

Documentation http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Missing quotes in the second version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `-` in an object property literal unless you  quote it. Either use camelCase or quote the property.

```
$('.player-window').css({paddingBottom: '50%'});
```

or

```
$('.player-window').css({'padding-bottom': '50%'});
```